# Phishing warning with Chrome about answer.

Tags: support, bug, google-chrome, warning

I just posted and answer at S.O. and the answer link when I visit it with chrome I get a phishing warning.

Someone should check: [CSRF state token does not match one provided FB PHP SDK 3.1.1 Oauth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977502/csrf-state-token-does-not-match-one-provided-fb-php-sdk-3-1-1-oauth-2-0/20313824#20313824)

Comment: I think also that the phishing warning was there before the answer but I am not 100% sure. I reported it as an incorrect warning but let's see. I am worried maybe I saw that in a different answer some time ago as well. Checking history

Comment: Not much we can do about this. This is a false positive on the end of Google / Chrome. Click the report an error link and submit a report for them. With enough of these, it will clear out.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Cool. Ok.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Can you tell why my answer was deleted?

Comment: No idea, but now it's undeleted.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeap it's resolved. Thanks